# How to split data's which are inside the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, underscore.js

I am trying to print the this array of data. My data looks like this:

```
[[["Not Critical","Not Critical"]],[["Not Critical","Not Critical"]],[["Not Critical","Not Critical"]]]
```

I need to print like this: (That means data which is inside every array has to be on the next line),

```
[
  [
    [
      "Not Critical",
      "Not Critical"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "Not Critical",
      "Not Critical"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "Not Critical",
      "Not Critical"
    ]
  ]
]
```

The output I am getting is:

```
[
  [
    ["Not Critical", "Not Critical"]
  ],
  [
    ["Not Critical", "Not Critical"]
  ],
  [
    ["Not Critical", "Not Critical"]
  ]

]
```

**Note** : I don't want to print every array on next line, instead of that, the data's which are inside the array's are have to  be print in the next line .

Comment: Add the code that you have tried out.

Comment: the two examples are the same. In the first one you just added a return to the beginning, end, and after the comma of the inner most array. Is there something else you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`space` parameter in JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```js
var data = [[["Not Critical","Not Critical"]],[["Not Critical","Not Critical"]],[["Not Critical","Not Critical"]]];

// Your data is now formatted like you want
var formattedData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

// So you can see it...
console.log(formattedData);
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that buddy ..print mean's , am going to print that in a pdf file

Comment: Wait... you're wanting to know how to how to print that to a pdf file?

Comment: Nope..I know how to print that into pdf , I need to print that  data which are inside the array's are in line by line (Like json format)

Comment: Did you try running the code snippet in my answer? It formats the data in the way you are looking for.

Comment: Sry buddy , just now seen that.. That is really helpfull . Thank you :)